# Incorrect decryption output when using CryptoJS library for AES

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt some random data using AES. I can successfully encrypt data using the following code,

```
function padString(source) {
  var paddingChar = 'x';
  var size = 16;
  var padLength = size - source.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < padLength; i++) source += paddingChar;

  return source;
}

var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('dassdadsasad');
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('fedcba9876543210');
var message = "0x72648174091c3f7cd41773f636ca9a15756798";
var padMsg = padString(message);

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(padMsg, key, {
  iv: iv,
  padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding,
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
});
```

but when I try to decrypt it,

```
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, {
  iv: iv,
  padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding,
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
});
```

I get the incorrect output for decryption instead of getting back my plain text.
Here is the output for instance,

```
Message: "0x72648174091c3f7cd41773f636ca9a15756798" 40

Padded message: "0x72648174091c3f7cd41773f636ca9a15756798" 40

Encrypted: 8qCjEtSLhchErbhJu8jo/xy8T5T1eSAFazuWLKwKdAW9F0ZUjJLlZw==

Encrypted text: f2a0a312d48b85c844adb849bbc8e8ff1cbc4f94f57920056b3b962cac0a7405bd1746548c92e567

Decrypted c748c55c0212d1688e79de5f00379eb0d802789501e6cbab3e6255b902eaa528a40d32123bcd0ce1
```

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong or if I am missing something ?

Here is the live demonstration, https://jsfiddle.net/4zb9hrxb/267/

Comment: Great question, but is this really the username you want to be known as on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1):

Your key is invalid:

```
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('dassdadsasad');
```

does not make much sense in the first place since `s` does not exist in hexadecimal notation. Either specify a 256 bit key as hex, like this:

```
key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("123456789012345678901234567890ab");
```

(note: only hexadecimal characters) or let CryptoJS derive the key from a passphrase:

```
var key = 'dassdadsasad';
```

Answer (score 0):

either follow what phihag said, or you can use some key derivation function such as, `PBKDF2` to derive key from passphrase (as phihag suggested).

consider this for example,

import [pbkdf2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2),

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/pbkdf2.js"></script>
```

and generate key as follows,

```
  var passphrase = "dassdadsasad"
  var keySize = 256;
  var iterations = 100;
  var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);
  var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(passphrase, salt, {
      keySize: keySize/32,
      iterations: iterations
    });
```

there is a very good example available here,

http://www.adonespitogo.com/articles/encrypting-data-with-cryptojs-aes/